# Make CSS loader output ES modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, css-loader

As far as I know, CSS loader outputs CommonJS, which doesn't work with some of Webpack's optimization features. Is there a way to make CSS loader output ES modules (`import`/`export`)?

Edit:

Here's what happens with ES modules:

main.js

```
import { FOO } from './module';
console.log(FOO);
```

output

```
var FOO = 'foo';
console.log(FOO);
```

And with CSS loader:

main.js

```
import { foo } from './styles.scss';
console.log(foo);
```

output

```
38: (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {
    module.exports = {"foo":"a"};
}),
...
var styles = __webpack_require__(38);
console.log(test["foo"]);
```

Comment: Can you please update as to which version of webpack and css-loader are you actually using?

Comment: Which version supports them? I'm using css-loader 3.0.0 and webpack 4.35.0

Comment: Then it's already supported according to their update in [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/612). Using css-loader with `https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader` will help you get the required output. In case you are not getting it, can you please show the code?

Comment: @LeoJiang, +1 thank you for this question! I don't know how to help you but I've had a lot of fun learning about CSS loader with this [Quick & Easy CSS Loaders](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BwhTKJFpKSw)

Comment: I already have postcss-loader, I added the output I see

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [post-css loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader) for this:

```sh
$ npm install -D postcss-loader
```

Then in your **webpack.config.js**:

```js
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { importLoaders: 1 } },
          'postcss-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```